# \end{center} error

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

Good evening,

I'd like to ask the following problem that i was unable to solve.

Computing a math text i obtained the following error just because i omitted a point after \end{center}.

this:

```
\begin{center}

$f(g_{1}) = f(g_{2})$,

\end{center} \\
```

doesn't compute.

This does:

```
\begin{center}

$f(g_{1}) = f(g_{2})$, 

\end{center}. \\
```

I'd like to know how to fix it becaus it is quite ugly to see a nosense point in my Notes,

thank you all, any help would be appreciated

Comment: What's the purpose of ``\\`` after `\end{center}` to begin with? Do you know about `\[...\]`, which is actually what you want?

Comment: I was going to ask the same thing as @egreg; and, why the period?

Comment: No @egreg could you explain better ?

Comment: I suppose the error you're getting is that there is no line to end. You are misusing ``\\`` It can only be used at the end of a line with content, you can't use it at the start of a line. After the `\end{center}` you're at the start of a line, so you can't have ``\\`` next. You need something in the line. Anything. It will work with `.` it will work with `a`, it will work with `elementary, my dear Watson` but  it won't work nothing.

Comment: @GuM i put the period because i noticed that with it computed but not without it

Comment: But ``\\`` is for use in tables and things, it's rarely the right thing to be used in the text, @egreg is saying you should have `text text text \[ f(g_{1}) = f(g_{2}), \] text text text`. He is right

Comment: @Au101 so should i remove \\ ?

Comment: It worked, thanks! (I'm sorry for this inconvenient)

Comment: @jacopoburelli no no! Never apologise! You did nothing wrong, you did the right thing by asking. It's never too early to stop someone from misusing ``\\``, you could have built up a really bad habit. Now you know =)

Comment: Not to contradict what @Au101 says, but you would had done an even better thing if you had sistematically studied an introductory guide to LaTeX.  Trying to learn it by asking one thing at a time makes for a very painful learning…

Comment: So when i should \\ ? Just understand it clearly @Au101

Comment: @jacopoburelli You should use it in `tabular`s, `array`s, `matrix` environments and the like, where you need to end rows. You can also use it in the `verse` environment, which is for poetry, where you want to break lines without ending paragraphs. Only use it to break a line in the middle if you have some positive reason for doing so. Never use it to end a paragraph, produce unjustified text, or something like that and steer clear of it is a quick way of adding a bit of vertical space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test document

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

Some text to fill a couple of lines before some displayed 
equation that is centered on a line by itself
\begin{center}
$f(g_{1})=f(g_{2})$
\end{center} \\
and some text following the display.

\end{document}
```

stops with the error

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.10 a
      nd some text following the display.
```

that should be self-explaining: there is no line to end after `\end{center}`. If you go past the error by hitting return, the document is produced:

[image]

The same would be obtained by omitting `\\`.

On the other hand, this is not the preferred method for displaying equations:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Some text to fill a couple of lines before some displayed
equation that is centered on a line by itself
\begin{equation*}
f(g_{1})=f(g_{2}) 
\end{equation*} 
and some text following the display.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}` you can use `\[...\]` (but the former is more convenient if you later decide to number your equation and just removing `*` is sufficient).

There are some subtle differences in the output, but the main one is that no page break can happen before the display. Remember not to leave a blank line before the display itself.

And remember that `\\` is ***not*** the method of choice to end paragraphs, for which a blank line should be used.

Please, make sure to read an introductory guide to LaTeX: see [Where do I start LaTeX programming?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/)